# Laravel 5: Class permission not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, permissions

In my routes file, I normally check against a single permission with `can:manage-admin`, which works fine.  I read in the documentation that checking against multiple permissions can be done with `permission` and `|` to separate them such as `permission:manage-admin|manage-whatever`.  I changed my `can` usaged to `permission` below and I am now getting an error "Class permission does not exist".

I posted my Permission.php file below the Routes below

**Routes**

```
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission:view-user|edit-labels']], function () {
            Route::post('admin/api/scan-barcode', 'Admin\UsersController@checkLabel');
        });
```

**Permissions.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Helpers;

use App\Models\User;

class Permissions
{
    /**
     * The user.
     *
     * @var App\Models\User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * The list of all possible permissions.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public static function list()
    {
        return [
            'view-user'          => 'View User',
            'edit-labels'        => 'Edit Labels',

        ];
    }

    public static function permissionKeys()
    {
        return array_keys(static::list());
    }

    public function has($permission)
    {
        if ($this->user->isSuperAdmin()) {
            return true;
        }

        if (isset($this->user->permissions['all-permissions']) && $this->user->permissions['all-permissions'] == true) {
            return true;
        }

        if (isset($this->user->permissions[$permission]) && $this->user->permissions[$permission] == true) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you missed ```'``` in ```'Edit Labels'``` end. put that and try.

Comment: sorry, just a typo putting it in StackOverflow